# Has the average native Japanese speaker heard of Hepburn romaji?

Tags: terminology, rōmaji

Is the average native Japanese speaker likely to have heard of Hepburn romaji? Not necessarily being able to recall the entire kana table, but at least knowing that it is a romanization system which has some kana different from other systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called ヘボン式ローマ字. 訓令式ローマ字 is taught in school but I think many Japanese know ヘボン式ローマ字.

Comment: I believe both systems are taught (not very thoroughly) in school. I think they almost no native speakers though have any clear idea as to which system is which, or what this has to do with computer input (which for no good reason does not accept any standard romanisation), which is why public signs etc are generally very haphazard.